# stagewebvie is not displaying page in ipad

Tags: apache-flex, flash-builder, stagewebview

I have written Code like

```
protected var swv:StageWebView = null;
private var url:String = new String(stringnaveed.text);
protected function view1_creationCompleteHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
        {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(StageWebView.isSupported == true)
        {                   
            swv = new StageWebView();
            swv.viewPort = new Rectangle(0,80,600,600);
            swv.stage = this.stage;
            swv.loadURL(url);
        }
    }
<s:Label id="stringnaveed" text="http://www.formpfplus.com/AI/new_faq.htm" visible="false">

</s:Label>
```

But When I diploying this on my device it doesnot show anything

Answer (score 0):

stagewebview is not available for the ipad, only for android. on blackberry you have to use qnxstagewebview.

Comment: I got solution, here is the code: //                          import flash.filesystem; protected var counter:int = 0; var url:String = File.applicationDirectory.nativePath+'\\Identifying Triangles by Angles.html' protected function button1_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void { trace(url); webView.stage = stage; webView.viewPort = new Rectangle(400, 400, 400, 400); webView.loadURL(url); }                                    protected function view1_creationCompleteHandler(event:FlexEvent):void { // TODO Auto-generated method stub }